# How can I render HTML from a string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a database variable from which I get this, for example:

```
hello, `<br />` have a good day,
```

It prints the `<br />` to my screen. How could I tell html that 
 is a line break?

My variable is called `greeting` and it is an array from which I use a for to print everything, but I used that little text as an example.

So I tried with innerHTML but it doesn't work:

```
  <i id="break" class="textTitle">{{ greeting }}</i>
      <script>
         document.getElementById("break").innerHTML = "<br/>";
      </script>
```

Comment: It should work just fine without any changes. It's probably your CSS that overrides this behavious.

Comment: Your question was confusingly specific. It doesn't really relate to line breaks, but HTML in general. I've revised the title to ask a more general question.

Comment: Does your  string actually have backticks in it, or was that just an attempt at formatting in this post?

Comment: Your embedded script element is an anti-pattern with respect to React. It might help if you'd provide a bit more context.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work for me :(, I have this text in a timeline, I already tried to modify the css as you mention but I don't know what the error is

Comment: Why did you switch this to an angular question?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop:

```
<i id="break" class="textTitle" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={greeting}></i>
```

Your original code uses innerText under the hood to set the content of the element. That's why it gets interpreted as text instead of HTML code.

```
<i id="break" class="textTitle">{{ greeting }}</i>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried like this but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Your question had react in the tags so I provided a solution for react, but I see now that you changed it to angular

Answer (score -1):

In must be something to do with the way you interpreter is treating the text, as this should normally work fine:

```js
document.getElementById("break").innerHTML = "<br/>";
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Hi</h1>
 <h1 id="break"></h1>
 <h1>There</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried that way but it doesn't work :(